# How do I check if Email ID Exists on Sheet, and Go To Next Email ID in Thread?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

First off: JavaScript novice. Any help/direction you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

I have an Apps Script I'm working on in Google Sheets for a business case. I'm reading through a labeled e-mail thread, and am getting the attachment out of it. However, this e-mail comes from a vendor 4 times a day. Rather than importing every file in it, I need to only process email ID's that I haven't recorded in `previousIDs`.

Below is the beginning part of my code, with the rest of the action I need to perform left off since it's working correctly.

```
function functionName() {

    // Google Sheet Record Details
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('GoogleSheetName');
    var initialSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportInitial');
    var downloadSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportForDownload');
    var historicalSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportHistorical');
    var historicalAttachments = ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalAttachmentNames');

    // GMail Details
    var gmailLabel = ('_Projects/Doc Cancel/New Requests');
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabel);
    var unreadCount = label.getUnreadCount();
    var gmailThreads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabel).getThreads();
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(gmailThreads);

    // Get Previous Email IDs to prevent duplicates
    var previousIDs = historicalAttachments.getRange("D2:D").getValues()
        .filter(function(row) {
            return row[0];
        })
        .sort();

    // Begin loop through Messages
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

        // Begin loop through individual emails within Message
        for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
            var attachments = messages[i][j].getAttachments();
            var emailDate = messages[i][j].getDate();
            var emailID = messages[i][j].getId();

            for (p in previousIDs) {
                if (emailID == previousIDs[p][0]) {
                    // stop this loop, and go to the next message[i]
                }
            }

            // if emailID does not exist in list of previousIDs
            if (attachments != '') {
            // rest of code goes here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a solution, but definitely welcome any insight.

The code below appears to work:

```
function functionName() {

    // Google Sheet Record Details
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('GoogleSheetName');
    var initialSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportInitial');
    var downloadSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportForDownload');
    var historicalSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ExportHistorical');
    var historicalAttachments = ss.getSheetByName('HistoricalAttachmentNames');

    // GMail Details
    var gmailLabel = ('_Projects/Doc Cancel/New Requests');
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabel);
    var unreadCount = label.getUnreadCount();
    var gmailThreads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabel).getThreads();
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(gmailThreads);

    // Get Previous Email IDs to prevent duplicates
    var previousIDs = historicalAttachments.getRange("D2:D").getValues()
        .filter(function (row) {
            return row[0];
        })
        .sort();

    // Begin loop through Messages
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

        // Begin loop through individual emails within Message
        var j = 0;
        emailIDLoop:
            for (j; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
                var attachments = messages[i][j].getAttachments();
                var emailDate = messages[i][j].getDate();
                var emailID = messages[i][j].getId();

                for (var p = 0; p < previousIDs.length; p++) {
                    if (emailID == previousIDs[p][0]) {
                        continue emailIDLoop;
                    }
                }

                // if emailID does not exist in list of previousIDs
                if (attachments != '') {
                // rest of code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try using continue

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

```
    // Begin loop through Messages
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

        // Begin loop through individual emails within Message
        for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
            var attachments = messages[i][j].getAttachments();
            var emailDate = messages[i][j].getDate();
            var emailID = messages[i][j].getId();
```

> Try this from here:

```
            var found=false;
            for (p in previousIDs) {
                if (emailID == previousIDs[p][0]) {
                    found=true;
                }
            }
            if(found){continue;}
```

> to here:

```
            // if emailID does not exist in list of previousIDs
            if (attachments != '') {
            // rest of code goes here
```